# Pytorch Lightning Tensorboard logger automatically adds "epoch" scalar

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

As in: [How do you prevent the tensorboard logger in pytorch lightning from logging the current epoch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183125/how-do-you-prevent-the-tensorboard-logger-in-pytorch-lightning-from-logging-the)

Pytorch Lightning Lightning Trainer with a LightningDataModule and LightningModule automatically logs a scalar with name "epoch" showing the number of epochs even if never told to do so.

How do I remove/ control that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

### In Short

You can disable automatically writing `epoch` variable by overwriting tensorboard logger.

```py
from pytorch_lightning import loggers
from pytorch_lightning.utilities import rank_zero_only

class TBLogger(loggers.TensorBoardLogger):
    @rank_zero_only
    def log_metrics(self, metrics, step):
        metrics.pop('epoch', None)
        return super().log_metrics(metrics, step)
```

I already answer to question you mentioned. So if you want to see full long version, go to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70183125/how-do-you-prevent-the-tensorboard-logger-in-pytorch-lightning-from-logging-the).